# Determine if gaussian blur is set with a script in adobe illustrator

Tags: javascript, adobe, extend, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I have a variety of documents in adobe illustrator. I have a script that performs certain tasks on them, however I don't need all the tasks performed on all of the documents. I need some tasks to be performed only on documents with a gaussian blur set. I have no problem scripting the tasks in JavaScript but I can't figure out for the life of me how to determine using JavaScript if a blur is set on an object in a layer. I know how to loop through the objects and layers, I just don't know what property to look for to determine if the blur is set and by how many pixels the blur is set. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a graphic style on the object, you can at least determine that it is associated with it by a crude way of pasting the object into a new temp document and taking a read of any new graphic styles which appear in the graphic styles panel.
Other means of determining non-script accessible styles on art may involve expanding the art (probably duplicate it first) and checking if any rasters appeared where there only are supposed to be vectors.
This is really a weak point for scripting and solutions such as these are only for particular subsets of cases.
It may however be possible to make a plugin which gets called by the script, but that would involve the Illustrator SDK and C++